# VMware virtual WindowsXP - VMDK or ISO for a third person who is going to use it

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, iso-image

Our team made a little application, then created in VMware Player a Windows XP virtual OS and installed the application into it. Now the guy who is going to use wants us to make an image of it, burn it on a DVD and send it to him. What exactly should I burn on a DVD ? Does he need .ISO or .VMDK file ? He will then run that virutal Windows XP on his PC via VMware Player as we did.

Comment: Note that there are possible license issues around the XP VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should burn the .VMDK, and .VMX files on the DVD. **The best if you burn the whole directory, where the virtual machine is.**

This way he can copy the files to his PC to run the VM. You can't run the VM on the DVD, though.